# Maximum of a vector field

Tags: vector-fields

Lets say a vector field represents the speed of a river

$$F = (-x/20, 20 - x^2 / 1000)\quad 100 \le x \le 100$$

Find the $x$ and $y$ values of the maximum speed in the river.

The norm of the feild yeilds the length of a vector at any (x, y).

|F| = (x^4 - 37500x^2 + 400000000)^1/2 / 1000

the solution is (0, 20) because at x = 0 |F| is horizontal and a maximum.

Maximize this function.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please avoid posting question that consist merely of the problem statement and show us your work.

Comment: Maybe it is convenient to indicate the components of $F$ by $F_x$ and $F_y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that for $F=(F_x,F_y)$

$$|F|=\sqrt{F_x^2+F_y^2}$$

Comment: of so if i was to guess that would yield a function that i could maximize using standard maximization techniques of a function of 1 variable?

Comment: @SwimMaster Yes of course!

Comment: @SwimMaster Try to solve in that way and show your work editing your qeustion.